# ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module

Tags: angular

I've got this error when trying to build my angular project :

> ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module
>   C:/Users/Admin/ifinish-web/node_modules/angular2-cool-storage/index.d.ts,
>   found ver sion 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   C:/Users/Admin/ifinish-web/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol
>   AppModule in  C:/Users/Admin/ifinish-web/src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

This suggests angular2-cool-storage requires Angular 5+, but your project is supplying Angular 4. To resolve, you could either:

1. Upgrade to Angular 5, or
2. Pin your angular2-cool-storage dependency version specifier to an earlier version that does not depend on Angular 4. If you go this route, it looks like angular2-cool-storage only has one release, so you cannot use a regular npm module dependency, but instead you would need to use a [git dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies), e.g. on commit [9e230d4e20dd08eaa0a52ce3d08774614caf67dd](https://github.com/Hacklone/angular2-cool-storage/tree/9e230d4e20dd08eaa0a52ce3d08774614caf67dd).

I posted a more general solution here:

[ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module X found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534610/error-in-metadata-version-mismatch-for-module-x-found-version-4-expected-3-res/47534611#47534611)